# Reset popover after closing it

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

**THE ACTION**

I am using Bootstrap popovers within a page. I show a popover, then close it when an action from within it is actioned, there is no page refresh.

**THE PROBLEM**

After closing the popover, when I click on the link again to show it again, I have to click the link twice... presumably once to initialise again, then once to show it.

**TRIED SOLUTION**

I firstly, initialise the popovers on page load, then call the function which does this:

```
function init_popovers(){
    $('.ci__popover').popover(); 

    // individual popovers
    $('.gender1_iq').popover({
        html : true,
        content: function() {
            return $('#gender1_iq').html();
        }
    });
}

// first time around, initialise popovers
init_popovers();
```

Then I perform the action and close the popover:

```
$(document).on('click', '.gender1__pop', function(){
    // do something

    // now close the popovers and initialise
    $('.popover').fadeOut(function(){ // hide all popovers
        init_popovers(); // now initialise popovers
    });

});
```

**THE RESULT**

This simply doesn't do anything it seems, I still have to click twice after closing a popover to show it again.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?